# C++: Sort functions

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I am a C++ beginner. I want to understand how is this `function` operating on a `string` to sort it?

```
int SA_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) { return strcmp(S + *(int*)a, S + *(int*)b); }
```

any pointer will help?

Comment: A word of advice: abandon the above and go with the [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: What is `S`? Whatever learning material you are using: Throw it away NOW. Get a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead. That is terrible code and should not be shown to a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a **C** comparison function, not a (C++) sorting function.  A sort function (probably [qsort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort), given the `const void*` arguments) would call it a number of times (passing it pointers to what are apparently indices into a buffer containing a number of null-terminated strings) in order to sort those indices (and, indirectly, the substrings they indicate).

Answer (score 1):

This will *not* sort a string.

This is a method that helps comparing strings and is used by sorthing methods as a helper method.

It will return a negative number if string `a` is lexicographically smaller than string `b`, 0 if they are equal, or a positive number if `b` is greater than `a`.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. The initial answer got me confused and threw me in an abyss of deep self-doubts :D